# Sending keystrokes to cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-events

Is it possible to send keystrokes to a cocoa app? I don't want to use AppleScript because I want to do it under the hood, programatically. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these calls, but you will need to set `code` correctly which can be dependent of the currently selected keyboard.

```
CGEventRef event;
event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, code, down);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event);
CFRelease(event);
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent

Comment: Thanks for the input, but how do I send it to a specific application running in the background?

Comment: Use `CGEventPostToPSN` instead.